# Grid sticky option doesn't shrink slave

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I'm trying to create GUI that contain three canvases.

The view I want to create is as following:

```
--------------------------------------------
|    |                                |    |
|    |                                |    |
|    |                                |    |
|    |                                |    |
--------------------------------------------
```

Two narrow canvases on left and right , and one big canvas in center.
This is my code:

```
#!/bin/sh  
# \
exec wish "$0" 

canvas .lib
canvas .lef -background "black"
canvas .lay

grid .lib -row 0 -column 0 -sticky ns 
grid .lef -row 0 -column 1 -sticky nsew
grid .lay -row 0 -column 2 -sticky ns

# Added as proposed by Donal Fellows
grid columnconfigure . 1 -weight 1
```

But instead order I described above I get all canvases in the same size.

[image: canvases]

Comment: Can you explicitly set the width of the canvases?

Comment: [This](http://i.stack.imgur.com/umSVG.png) is what I get if I specify the canvas width (e.g. `canvas .lib -row 0 -column 0 -sticky ns -width 100` the middle at 500 and the right at 100).

Comment: Yes! it did the work. Thanks ,Jerry!

Comment: @Jerry I think you can submit your comment as answer, so I can mark it as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't 'fix' column widths for the canvases, you could set a specific width with the `-width` option when creating the canvas:

```
canvas .lib -width 100
canvas .lef -background "black" -width 500
canvas .lay -width 100
```

And with everything else the same, the result I get is:

[image]

If you want to later change the width of the canvas, you can of course use something like `.lib configure -width 200` to change the width of the `.lib` canvas to 200 px.

Answer (score 0):

The grid geometry manager uses a weighting system to reassign extra space to columns (and rows), yet all columns (and rows) start with zero weight, so extra space doesn't get allocated at all by default. You've got to explicitly give that column a non-zero weight.

```
grid columnconfigure . 1 -weight 1
```

Note that the weight applies to the whole column, not individual widgets in it, so the weighting can't be set when you're adding the widget.

Comment: I've added this command to my script and got :  Error in startup script: expected integer but got "-weight" (when retreiving options only integer indices are allowed)
    while executing
"grid columnconfigure . -weight 1" 

So I updated it to: grid columnconfigure . 0 -weight 1
The script started without error but it creates the same window as on attached picture. Only when I resize it the column 0 shrink when 2 other remain the same. I my example I want to get two narrow and one big canvases on the start.

Comment: @RomanKaganovich Oh yes, forgot to tell it which column to give the weight to. :-) Columns and rows are numbered from 0. The initial sizes are also determined by the “natural” sizes of the widgets. Try setting the `-width` option on the canvases as well.